# Add class to HTML element of the child component according to parent component property - Angular

Tags: angular

Let's say I have a `SidebarComponent` component:

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  isExpanded: boolean = true;

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  }

}
```

So on button click I could add a class to that component's DIV:

`<div class="sidebar" [ngClass]="isExpanded ? '' : 'sidebar--hidden'">...`

And another component - `SubSidebarComponent` - which extends `SidebarComponent`:

```
export class SubSidebarComponent extends SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { 
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

So could accordingly add class to it's DIV as well:

`<div class="sub-sidebar" [ngClass]="isExpanded ? 'a' : 'b'">...`

Above logic obviously doesn't work and child's `isExpanded` is always `true` (always 'a' class added).

How could I achieve this in a minimalist, similar to above way?

Comment: Why doesn't work? should be working, can you add {{isExpanded}} in your child and change the value on parent, logically it should be changed there

Comment: how about adding a method to child component `getExpanded() {return this.isExpanded;}` and `<div class="sub-sidebar" [ngClass]="getExpanded() ? 'a' : 'b'">...`

Comment: see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7teznd

Comment: @RezaRahmati thanks, your example is exactly what I need and it works! Will try to find out code differences because now it seems the same!

Comment: @fuji btw your solution is not the best, alway prefer composition over inheritance

Comment: BTW [ngClass]="{'sidebar--hidden': isExpanded}" looks more clear

Comment: @RezaRahmati thanks for advise, I will then look into composition now. But now I see the difference in your example - the point is I have to trigger `isExpanded` of child component from parent component.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko what about [class.sidebar--hidden]="isExapnded" ;)

Comment: @fuji the example also changes the value from parent method `toggle`, it changes in parent, since you inherit the class no html can be displayed from parent

Comment: @RezaRahmati isExapnded will be `false` constantly ;)

Comment: @RezaRahmati this is what I want to achieve - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2afgj

Comment: @fuji sorry I didn't get your point, you put two components on your page which will be two separate objects (each one has it's own isExpanded) and you want when you change parent component variable, the other instance variable changes?  
This is like creating two object from an inherited classes and you want changes in one object affects the other one